# file outbound channel and remote directory expression

Tags: spring, directory, integration, spring-el

I'm try to combine both a SpEL and a bean value to generate a

```
directory-expression="${backup.folder}'+T(java.io.File).separator+new    java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyyMMdd').format(new java.util.Date())"
```

in a

```
int-file:outbound-channel-adapter
```

, but it does not work.

The problem is on retrieving the properties ( $(backup.folder)) value, as it yields a NullPointerException.

Do i need to use a different syntax for it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should get resolved - but you have a missing opening single quote `"${backup.folder}'...`
should be `"'${backup.folder}'...`. I am not sure why you are getting a NPE rather than a `EL1046E:(pos 74): Cannot find terminating  for string` though.

Comment: Yes true, my answer is not correct - with quote it does resolve cleanly

Comment: Thanks again, gary, you're the one. This made it. I knew it was some syntax problem.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>It looks like property place holder does not resolve in a Spring-EL expression</strike>. 
Another workaround will be to reference a bean instead with `@bean` type expression, with the bean populated using the PropertyPlaceHolder expression. for eg:

```
<bean name="aString" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="${backup.folder}"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

directory-expression="@aString + T(java.io.File).separator+...
```

EDIT:

Found that the propertyplaceholder does resolve in a expression based on Gary's answer.

Comment: Yes, property place holders are resolved, as i have something similar            in     release-strategy-expression="size() == ${ftp.max.in.size}" . For information, i'm using Spring-Int 2.2.3

Comment: Gary's answer is correct, with a single quote the PropertyPlaceHolder does resolve cleanly!